# Alternative solution to require audio dynamically using expo-av

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm developing an audio application where I download all the audio files at once and then play them using expo-av library. The issue is when I try to require the audio file, I get the following error

```
Invalid call at line 77: require(audioUrl)
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

I'm aware that we cannot require dynamically in react-native. I would like to know if there is any alternative solution to play downloaded audios?

The function where I require downloaded audio file

```
const _loadNewPlaybackInstance = async isPlaying => {
    if (playBackInstance != null) {
      await playBackInstance.unloadAsync()
      await setPlaybackInstance(null)
    }
    const source = require(audioUrl)
    const initialStatus = {
      shouldPlay: isPlaying,
      volume,
      rate: audioRate,
      shouldCorrectPitch: true,
      pitchCorrectionQuality: Audio.PitchCorrectionQuality.Low
    }
    const { sound, status } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      source,
      initialStatus,
      _onPlaybackStatusUpdate
    )
    setPlaybackInstance(sound)
    _updateScreenForLoading(false)
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, `require` is for static resources, not dynamic ones. According to documentation [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#audiosound), the source parameter can be one of three types.

> - **source (object / number / Asset)** -- The source of the sound. The following forms are supported:
>
>   - A dictionary of the form `{ uri: string, headers?: { [string]: string }, overrideFileExtensionAndroid?: string }`with a network URL pointing to a media file on the web, [...]
>   - require('path/to/file') for an audio file asset in the source code directory.
>   - An Asset object for an audio file asset.

You can use the first type of parameter for dynamic resources. You would do:

`const source = { uri: audioUrl }` where `audioUrl` can be a local resource as well: `file:///path/to/resource`

Comment: I have audio files in the source code directory, but I need to load them dynamically (the user may be shown any of hundreds of flash cards, and I need to grab the correct audio file depending on which card is randomly shown).  Since 'require' will only take a fixed string (not a computed one), how can I use the URI option to grab a local file?  In other words, is the 'file:///path/to/resource' protocol able to point to files within the source code directory, and if so, how do I know what path the files are placed in?

Comment: @Byofuel Did you ever figure out a solution to this?